# How to develop a robust UDP Client in python?

Tags: python, udp

I have to develop a UDP Client in Python. The purpose of the UDP client is to receive the packets via a port and process it (requires a map lookup) and then publish the processed data to a Kafka topic. The number of Packets received in a second is more than 2000.

I have tried a code which is as shown below. But there are packet losses.

```
import socket
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=config.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER,
        value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('ascii'),security_protocol='SSL')


client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client_socket.settimeout(1.0)
addr = ("0.0.0.0", 5000)
client_socket.bind(addr)
while True:
     data, server = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
     d_1 = some_logic()
     producer.send("XYZ",d_1)
```

Please suggest me a approach with a small code snippet to perform this activity without or minimal packet loss

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you measure the packet data loss ? Is it actually caused by the code you are showing ? Because 2000/s is not a lot, at all, even for Python. Considering a typical payload size of 65,507 for UDP, it means you want to process ~130 Mo/s. Have you tried to profile your code to see what is slow ? It could well be crypting (SSL), or JSON-encoding your data. WOuld you consider using a different language for better performance, if needs be ?

Comment: Currently, I am comparing the packets received in tcpdump and the ones received in the code. So, I found there were some packets missing in the application code logs . The UDP Packets are less than 1024 bytes. The processing of Packets does not take more than 1 ms. For now, I like to stick to python, but open to suggestions in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code :

`sender.py`

```py
import socket

import tqdm  # pip install

# example data from https://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html
data = '\
[{"id":"0001","type":"donut","name":"Cake","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"1003","type":"Blueberry"},{"id":"1004","type":"Devil\'s Food"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5007","type":"Powdered Sugar"},{"id":"5006","type":"Chocolate with Sprinkles"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0002","type":"donut","name":"Raised","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0003","type":"donut","name":"Old Fashioned","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]}]\
'.encode("ascii")
assert len(data) == 1011, len(data)  # close to the 1000 you average in your case

sender_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sender_socket.settimeout(1.0)  # 1 second is laaarge
addr = ("127.0.0.1", 6410)
sender_socket.connect(addr)

progress_bar = tqdm.tqdm(unit_scale=True)
while True:
    bytes_sent = sender_socket.send(data)
    assert bytes_sent == 1011, bytes_sent
    progress_bar.update(1)
```

`receiver.py`

```py
import json
import socket

import tqdm  # pip install

receiver_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
receiver_socket.settimeout(5.0)
addr = ("127.0.0.1", 6410)
receiver_socket.bind(addr)

progress_bar = tqdm.tqdm(unit_scale=True)
while True:
    data_bytes, from_address = receiver_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    data = json.loads(data_bytes)
    progress_bar.update(1)
```

(using `tqdm` for easy speed monitoring)

I am around ~80 K it/s on my computer, which is roughly 80 times more than your case.
Try it yourself, see how much you get. Then add `d_1 = some_logic()` and measure again. Then add `producer.send("XYZ",d_1)` and measure again.

This will give you a pretty good picture of what is slowing you. Then ask another question on the specific problem. Better if you produce a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

---

### Edit:

Indeed, the sender saturates the receiver, such that packets get dropped. It's because the receiver throughput is lower than the sender (because of the processing time), so here is an alternative :

`steady_sender.py`

```py
import socket
import time

import tqdm  # pip install

# example data from https://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html
data = '\
[{"id":"0001","type":"donut","name":"Cake","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"1003","type":"Blueberry"},{"id":"1004","type":"Devil\'s Food"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5007","type":"Powdered Sugar"},{"id":"5006","type":"Chocolate with Sprinkles"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0002","type":"donut","name":"Raised","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0003","type":"donut","name":"Old Fashioned","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]}]\
'.encode("ascii")
assert len(data) == 1011, len(data)  # close to the 1000 you average in your case

sender_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sender_socket.settimeout(1.0)  # 1 second is laaarge
addr = ("127.0.0.1", 6410)
sender_socket.connect(addr)

progress_bar = tqdm.tqdm(unit_scale=True)
while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    bytes_sent = sender_socket.send(data)
    assert bytes_sent == 1011, bytes_sent
    progress_bar.update(1)

    current_time = time.time()
    remaining_time = 0.001 - (current_time - start_time)  # until next millisecond
    time.sleep(remaining_time)
```

It tries to send one packet every millisecond. It stays around ~900 packets/s for me, because the code is too simple (falling asleep takes time too !).
This way, the receiver processes fast enough so that no packet gets dropped (because UDP).

But here is another version, where the sender is bursty : it sends 1000 packet then goes to sleep until the next second.

`bursty_sender.py`

```py
import socket
import time

import tqdm  # pip install

# example data from https://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html
data = '\
[{"id":"0001","type":"donut","name":"Cake","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"1003","type":"Blueberry"},{"id":"1004","type":"Devil\'s Food"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5007","type":"Powdered Sugar"},{"id":"5006","type":"Chocolate with Sprinkles"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0002","type":"donut","name":"Raised","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0003","type":"donut","name":"Old Fashioned","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]}]\
'.encode("ascii")
assert len(data) == 1011, len(data)  # close to the 1000 you average in your case

sender_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sender_socket.settimeout(1.0)  # 1 second is laaarge
addr = ("127.0.0.1", 6410)
sender_socket.connect(addr)

progress_bar = tqdm.tqdm(unit_scale=True)
while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    bytes_sent = sender_socket.send(data)
    assert bytes_sent == 1011, bytes_sent
    progress_bar.update(1)

    if progress_bar.n % 1000 == 0:
        current_time = time.time()
        remaining_time = 1.0 - (current_time - start_time)  # until next second
        time.sleep(remaining_time)
```

It sends on average ~990 packets per second (losing less time to getting in and out of sleep). But the receiver only handles ~280 per second, the rest got dropped because the burst filled the receiver's buffer.
If I'm sending bursts at 400/s I process ~160/s.

You can monitor the drop using your OS's tool for monitoring network packet drop, Python can't.

If you don't want to drop, another solution is to use a queue : have the first one simply read from the socket and adding it to the queue, and the other reads from the queue and process. But then you have to ensure that the queue does not grow too large.

I'm able to handle bursts of 50 with my current system config, nearly 100, but not 150.

Here is an example with the queue :
`queued_receiver.py`

```py
import json
import queue
import socket
import threading

import tqdm  # pip install

messages_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=-1)  # infinite
received_packets_bar = tqdm.tqdm(position=0, desc="received", unit_scale=True)
queue_size_bar = tqdm.tqdm(position=1, desc="queue size", unit_scale=True)
processed_packets_bar = tqdm.tqdm(position=2, desc="processed", unit_scale=True)


def read_from_the_socket_into_the_queue():
    receiver_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    receiver_socket.settimeout(5.0)
    addr = ("127.0.0.1", 6410)
    receiver_socket.bind(addr)
    while True:
        data_bytes, from_address = receiver_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        # no processing at all here ! we want to ensure the packet gets read, so that we are not dropping
        messages_queue.put_nowait(data_bytes)
        queue_size_bar.update(1)
        received_packets_bar.update(1)


def read_from_the_queue_and_process():
    while True:
        data_bytes = messages_queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)  # until a message is available
        data = json.loads(data_bytes)
        queue_size_bar.update(-1)
        processed_packets_bar.update(1)
        sum(range(10**5))  # slow computation, adjust


socket_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_from_the_socket_into_the_queue)
process_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_from_the_queue_and_process)
socket_thread.start()
process_thread.start()
```

Comment: One doubt while testing the snippet, I found that on the sender side the statistics shows 27.4Mit [00:58, 472kit/s] and on receiver side it shows 4.76Mit [01:01, 77.7kit/s]. Does it indicate a packet loss?

Comment: @VrashabKotian yes because the sender is literally flooding, sending too much packets, which get dropped when the receiving buffer gets full (contrary to TCP). If the receiver would be able to ingest faster, no packet would get dropped. I edit my answer examples about that.